# This regex is not valid for xsd

Tags: python, regex, xml, xsd, lxml

I want to validate a 2- or 3-letter iso code, but also allow it to be empty (so it can be 0, 2, or 3 characters).

```
'\w{2,3}|'
```

This works locally and also on http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html. However, when I try running it on an ubuntu machine, I get the following error:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xsd_url = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/movie.xsd.xml'
>>> xsd_contents = urllib2.urlopen(xsd_url).read()
>>> xmlschema_doc = etree.fromstring(xsd_contents)
>>> xmlschema=etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xmlschema.pxi", line 102, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:168126)
lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}pattern': 
The value '\w{2,3}|' of the facet 'pattern' is not a valid regular expression., line 58
```

What would be a better regex pattern for this? `(\w{2,3})?` also fails with `xsd`, so it needs to be something else.

Comment: Try using this regex if you only expect English letters: `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|`. I guess you do not expect numbers in the letter code.

Comment: Same result: `The value '[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|' of the facet 'pattern' is not a valid regular expression., line 62`

Comment: A better regular expression here is `([a-zA-Z]{2,3})?`

Comment: And perhaps, `(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?` is even better. Does it work? I have been checking the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#dt-regex), they also suggest `S{0,0}` to check for empty string. Also, what if you declare `xmlschema_doc = etree.XML(xsd_contents)`?